# is it essential to copy a returned struct from kernel space to user space?

Tags: c, struct, copy, system-calls

if I make a system call, say

`struct hostent * gethostbyaddr (const char *addr, int len, int family );`

and it returns a `struct*`, do i need to copy the struct to somewhere I "own" instead of using the pointer directly?

Comment: A typical implementation returns a pointer to thread-local storage.  If you make any additional calls then you'd better make a deep copy.  If you use threads and you're not sure if TLS is used then you'd better use a lock.

Comment: `gethostbyaddr` is not a system call but a library routine. Even if it were a system call, it wouldn't be returning a pointer into kernel space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation of `gethostbyaddr` [reads](http://linux.die.net/man/3/gethostbyaddr) (see Notes section):

> The functions gethostbyname() and gethostbyaddr() may return pointers
>   to static data, which may be overwritten by later calls. Copying the
>   struct hostent does not suffice, since it contains pointers; a deep
>   copy is required.

It means that you need to copy the struct if you want to be sure that it won't be overwritten by subsequent calls to `gethostbyaddr`.

But you really need to consider using [`getaddrinfo`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getaddrinfo) since `gethostbyaddr` is obsolete. With `getaddrinfo` you will not be asking this question because you'll need to allocate memory for the result yourself.

Comment: `Copying the struct hostent does not suffice` - doesn't it mean you can't copy the returned struct? `getaddrinfo` is the correct recommendation.

Comment: @ugoren: It means you can't use shallow copy, since the struct contains pointers to another structs, so you must use deep copy.

Comment: A deep copy isn't a very well-defined operation. It depends on the structure you want to copy. When you write "copy the struct", I think it implies a shallow copy.

Comment: @ugoren: I did't write anything about copying the struct myself, I just quoted the documentation, and the documentation *explicitly* says that a *deep* copy is required.

Comment: Quote: "It means that you need to copy the struct".

Comment: @ugoren: oh, now I seem to understand what you mean. *I* didn't write "*deep* copy" immediately after citing the documentation. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can use the pointer directly.

(Think about it: if the memory was inaccessible or unsafe to access, you won't be able to copy it; and vice versa, if you are able to copy it, you can as well use it inplace).

Comment: but how does OS know when to clear this memory? I fear that while I'm reading from that memory, the OS refreshes it...

Comment: @can.: the OS only touches the memory when your process exits. The pointer returned by `gethostbyaddr` is not a pointer into kernel space.

Comment: This differs from function to function and OS to OS. In my BSD, `gethostbyaddr` uses thread-local storage and states that the memory will only be overwritten by subsequent calls on this thread. In other implementations, `gethostbyaddr` may return thread-unsafe pointer to static data. Other functions may behave differently (e.g. require you to free the memory) — you should read the documentation for each one.